# Django {% url %} NoReverseMatch

Tags: python, django, url, view

I'm trying to make a link of the current `Laps` object `ID` in a template file, and for the life of me I cannot solve this error.

Here's my:

**error**

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/laps/
Django Version: 1.5.2
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'views.LapView' with arguments '(181,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import RedirectView
from laptimes import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url=reverse_lazy('laptimes:laps')), name='index'),
    url(r'^laps/$', views.LapsView.as_view(), name='laps'),
    url(r'^laps/powerlaps/$', views.PowerLapsView.as_view(), name='powerlaps'),
    url(r'^laps/starcar/$', views.StarCarView.as_view(), name='starcar'),
    url(r'^laps/formulaone/$', views.FormulaOneView.as_view(), name='formulaone'),
    # cars
    url(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url=reverse_lazy('laptimes:cars')), name='index'),
    url(r'^cars/$', views.CarsView.as_view(), name='cars'),
    url(r'^cars/manu/$', views.CarsManuView.as_view(), name='carsmanu'),
    # drivers
    url(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url=reverse_lazy('laptimes:drivers')), name='index'),
    url(r'^drivers/$', views.DriversView.as_view(), name='drivers'),
    url(r'^drivers/nat/$', views.DriversNatView.as_view(), name='driversnat'),
    # episodes
    url(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url=reverse_lazy('laptimes:episodes')), name='index'),
    url(r'^episodes/$', views.EpisodesView.as_view(), name='episodes'),
    # single lap
    url(r'^lap/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.LapView.as_view(), name='lap'),
)
```

**views.py**

```
# Create your views here.
from django.views import generic
from laptimes.models import *


class LapView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Lap
    template_name = 'laptimes/lap.html'



class LapsView(generic.ListView):

    template_name = 'laptimes/laps.html'
    context_object_name = 'laps'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Lap.objects.all()
```

**laps.html**

```
{% extends 'laptimes/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<h1>All Laps</h1>
{% if laps %}
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Ref</th>
                <th>Time</th>
                <th>Car</th>
                <th>Driver</th>
                <th>Episode</th>
                <th>Conditions</th>
                <th>Comment</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for lap in laps %}
            <tr>
                <td>{% url 'views.LapView' lap.id %}</td>
                <td>{{ lap.time_str }}</td>
                <td>{{ lap.car }}</td>
                <td>{{ lap.driver }}</td>
                <td>
                    {{ lap.episode|default_if_none:"" }}
                    {{ lap.episode.date|default_if_none:"" }}
                </td>
                <td>{{ lap.condition|default_if_none:"" }}</td>
                <td>{{ lap.comment|default_if_none:"" }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
        </table>
{% else %}
    <p>No laps are available.</p>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 6):

Solved the problem with the following:

```
<td><a href="{% url 'laptimes:lap' lap.id %}">Edit</a></td>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the view function, use url name as

```
<td>{% url 'lap' lap.id %}</td>
```

Comment: `Reverse for 'lap' with arguments '(181,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.` :S

Comment: @ツ.jp, or try `{% url 'lap' pk=lap.id %}`

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide unambiguous fully qualified names. Either use the full Python path to your view or the fully namespaced view name.

Either of these should work:

```
{% url 'laptimes.views.LapView' lap.id %}
{% url 'laptimes:lap' lap.id %}
```

No slacking now!

Comment: But why? the documentation says I just should put in [the url name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#url) and be done with it.